# Create generic ArrayList with initialCapacity in generic class

Tags: kotlin, generics, arraylist

I'm createing a generic ring buffer and I would like to use array list as internal storage for data and I'd like to allocate array list with defined `capacity`.

This is an example using Kotlin ArrayList:

```kotlin
class RingBuffer<T>(private val capacity: Int) {
    private var buffer = ArrayList<T>(initialCapacity = capacity)
}
```

When I compile the code, this error appears:

> Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
> public final fun  (): kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* = java.util.ArrayList */ defined in kotlin.collections.ArrayList
> public final fun  (p0: (MutableCollection<out T!>..Collection<T!>?)): kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* = java.util.ArrayList */ defined in kotlin.collections.ArrayList
> public final fun  (p0: Int): kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* = java.util.ArrayList */ defined in kotlin.collections.ArrayList

I've tried to use Java ArrayList:

```kotlin
import java.util.ArrayList
class RingBuffer<T>(private val capacity: Int) {
    private var buffer = ArrayList<T>(capacity)
}
```

In this case code compiles, but `buffer` has `size=0`, so array is not allocated.

So the question is how to create and then allocate `ArrayList` with `default T` values?

Comment: `size` is not the same as `capacity`. `size` is 0 because the list contains nothing, but the underlying array should still be allocated with its capacity = `capacity`. If you really want to set a default value you can use something like `MutableList(capacity){ default }`

Comment: @gpunto thanks. This is works `var buffer = MutableList<T?>(capacity) { null }`. Do you know if it's possible to omit nullability, to make it like `var buffer = MutableList<T>(capacity) { default(T) }`. For example this `default(T)` is possible in C#, but I'm not sure if there is something similar in Kotlin or Java?

Comment: Are you aware that Kotlin 1.4 (just released) [adds a new ArrayDeque class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#new-functions-for-arrays-and-collections)?  Maybe that does what you want?

Comment: @gidds yep, I know about ArrayDeque. I'm implementing some data strucrures in Kotlin just for fun, to learn the language and understand how to write stuff in ideomatic Kotlin.

Comment: @VadimSentiaev That's great!  (But I'll leave my comment, in case other readers don't know about it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do it this way:

```kotlin
class RingBuffer<T>(size: Int) {
    private var buffer = MutableList<T?>(size) { null }
}
```

This is fine to have nullable `T?` because `read` method will have this signature:

```kotlin
fun read(): T?
```

Comment: `capacity` is wrong here. the parameter you use is actually `size`. Also, the parameter of your constructor does not need to be a property (leave out `private val`)